# How to delete all characters in text file by python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file `namefile.txt` which has more character. I want to delete all text and keep the file in order to see nothings when we open `namefile.txt` after run the python script?

Comment: Can you rephrase your intention. I don't understand what you are trying to do at all.

Comment: @EyuelDK The intent seems clear: clear out the contents of a file.

Comment: I want to delete all the text in namefile.txt

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service We try to fix your code, we do not write your code –

Comment: some good guys answer me after you.Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This will do it. Opening a file with write permission conceptually clears previous data.

```
open('namefile.txt', 'w').close()
```

Comment: yep, what thousands and even millions of programmers have done by accident to important files.

Comment: you're welcome :) mark answer if the issue has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

Simply open the file in write mode and close it

```
f = open('myfile.dat', 'w')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the file open, you can also call :
    file.truncate()